# nfc-list not showing device

Tags: kali-linux

I have plugged in my Nexus 4 via USB and I'm running nfc-list on Kali Linux 2.0.
But when running the command I only receive 'no device found'. Is the Nexus 4 not compatible with nfc-list??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nfc-list` is not reporting the NFC device because what you have done is connected the phone containing the NFC module to the computer. The Nexus phone is what is responsible for enumerating and operating the NFC module. Your computer is expecting a NFC device to be directly connected and enumerable; instead what is connected is the USB interface the Android phone provides.

You can probably use or write an android application which uses the Android's NFC and communicates with your pc via LAN or USB. You might even be able to manipulate the Android OS into letting your PC's USB enumerate the Android's NFC. I expect the latter to be quite complicated and difficult, and the former is probably just as difficult if you want to use programs that use directly enumerated devices. I think you're better off trudging through all the terrible apps available for Android while searching for something that does whatever the Kali program you want to use does.

Comment: Ok thank you, but is there a way to bypass the android OS and communicate directly with the NFC module?

Comment: @wasp256 I went ahead and appended my answer.